# How to allow specific LDAP users to authenticate oracle linux servers?

Tags: ldap, openldap, sssd

```
$ sudo grep -v -E '^\s*(#|$)' /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
SASL_NOCANON    on
uri ldap://ldap.local.{company}.com
base dc={company},dc=com
$  sudo grep -v -E '^\s*(#|$)' /etc/pam.d/sshd

auth     sufficient     pam_ldap.so
auth     sufficient     pam_unix.so
account  sufficient     pam_ldap.so
account  sufficient     pam_unix.so
auth     required       pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow file=/etc/ldap.allowedusers
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    required     pam_sepermit.so
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    optional     pam_motd.so
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
$
$ sudo cat /etc/ldap.allowedusers
ldapuser1
$ sudo grep -v -E '^\s*(#|$)' /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:     files ldap
group:      files ldap
netgroup:   sss files
automount:  sss files
services:   sss files
shadow:     files sss
hosts:      files dns myhostname
aliases:    files
ethers:     files
gshadow:    files
networks:   files dns
protocols:  files
publickey:  files
rpc:        files
$ sudo grep -v -E '^\s*(#|$)'  /etc/nslcd.conf
uid nslcd
gid ldap
uri ldap://ldap.local.{company}.com/
base dc={company},dc=com
$
```

Above are configs. I was able to ssh into above oracle 8 linux VM using bothe LDAP users and VM regular internal user.

I want to restrict the VM access to only specice set up users ? for this i added " auth required pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow file=/etc/ldap.allowedusers " in /etc/pam.d/sshd files and allowed only ldapuser1 in /etc/ldap.allowedusers Its not working, I'm still able to access with non-listed ldap user ex:ldapuser2

What mistake i'm doing here...

Added /removed users in $ sudo cat /etc/ldap.allowedusers then restart serversudo systemctl restart sshd still no use.. unable to restrict access to only some LDAP users, Note internal users continue to access the server for sudo duties.